# Android devloper tool is not opening

Tags: android

Android develoment tool is not opening while click this dailog is opening

my ubuntu version is 12.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is going to be difficult for people to help unless you provide more information. How did you install? How exactly are you trying to open it? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? Please edit your question with these details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install it following the Youtube tutorial? Then you might have disabled some file permissions and Nautilus options.

Open Nautilus. Go with your mouse to upside panel, which should show main menu, in this case only "Files"-option. Open preferences (or something like that). Second tab, Behaviour. In "Executable text files" mark "Ask..." - Close.

Go to unpacked Emulator-archive - Tools - Rightclick on Android - Permissions - Mark "Allow run file as program" if it is not marked. Close.

Then double click on Android and select "Run in terminal".